# Upserting a postgres jsonb based on multiple properties in jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, upsert

I am trying to upsert into a table with jsonb field based on multiple json properties in the jsonb field using below query

```
insert into testtable(data) values('{
    "key": "Key",
    "id": "350B79AD",
    "value": "Custom"
}')
On conflict(data ->>'key',data ->>'id')
do update set data =data || '{"value":"Custom"}'
WHERE data ->> 'key' ='Key' and data ->> 'appid'='350B79AD'
```

Above query throws error as below

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->>"
LINE 8: On conflict(data ->>'key',data ->>'id')
```

**am I missing something obvious here?**

Comment: The conflict target has to be a unique constraint or, as a shortcut, the columns which are unique.  You can't choose part of a jsonb object.

Comment: So. Seems like only way to do this is get the json first and update or insert?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to insert unique `id` and `key` combination value into the table. Then you need a unique constraint for them :

```
create unique index on testtable ( (data->>'key'), (data->>'id') );
```

and also use extra parentheses for the `on conflict` clause as tuple :

```
on conflict( (data->>'key'), (data->>'id') )
```

and qualify the jsonb column name ( `data` ) by table name (`testtable`) whenever you meet  after `do update set` or after `where` clauses as `testtable.data`. So, convert your statement to :

```
insert into testtable(data) values('{
    "key": "Key",
    "id": "350B79AD",
    "value": "Custom1"
}')
    on conflict( (data->>'key'), (data->>'id') )
    do update set data = testtable.data || '{"value":"Custom2"}'
 where testtable.data ->> 'key' ='Key' and testtable.data ->> 'id'='350B79AD';
```

btw, `data ->> 'appid'='350B79AD'` converted `to data ->> 'id'='350B79AD'` ( `appid` -> `id` )

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=290825d6b538b9706dcfed93c00360cf)</kbd>